# How to write XML file using for loop to append elements

Tags: c#, xml

I got a listbox of files. so I want to add this list's item to element of XML.
However, I have a problem with dealing a loop for adding items to XML.

```cs
//My goal:

//<project>
       <drawing>
//        file1 
//        file2
//    <drawing/>
//<project>
```

```cs
//I tried to add items to element 

//however it looks like

<drawing> file1file2 </drawing>
```

```cs
   List<string> drawingList = new List<string>();

   drawingList.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());

    new XDocument(
                        new XElement("Project",
                            new XElement("Name", project.name),
                            new XElement("Path", project.path),
                            new XElement("Drawing", drawingList)
                        )
                    )
                    .Save(@"C:\Users\for\Desktop\abc1.cadiprj");
);
```

Comment: Your code is not a proper [mcve] do note you are missing the declaration of `drawingList` variable. Is it a `List<string>`?

Comment: @bradbury9 Thanks for your comment. Yeah List<string> drawingList = new List<string>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication120
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> drawingList = new List<string>() { "file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"};

            XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("Project",
                    new XElement("Name", "abc"),
                    new XElement("Path", @"c:\temp\"),
                     new XElement("Drawing")
                )
           );
            XElement xDrawing = doc.Descendants("Drawing").FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (string drawing in drawingList)
            {
                xDrawing.Add(new XElement("Drawing", drawing));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the files separated in different lines you can `string.Join()` with a nuew line as separator

```
List<string> drawingList = new List<string>() { "file1", "file2"};

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Project",
        new XElement("Name", "abc"),
        new XElement("Path", @"c:\temp\"),
         new XElement("Drawing", string.Join("\n", drawingList.ToArray()))
    )
);
```

This would give you this output

```
<Project>
    <Name>abd</Name>
    <Path>your path</Path>
    <Drawing>
        file1
        file2
    </Drawing>
</Project>
```

As an advice, I would suggest a different format if it is not fixed, this one would make mucho more sense IMHO:

```
<Project>
    <Name>abd</Name>
    <Path>your path</Path>
    <Drawing>
        <file>file1</file>
        <file>file2</file>
    </Drawing>
</Project>
```